# modelling an infinite series in R

Tags: r, for-loop, taylor-series

I'm trying to write a code to approximate the following infinite Taylor series from the Theis hydrogeological equation in R.

[image: Well equation (part of the Theis equation]

I'm pretty new to functional programming, so this was a challenge! This is my attempt:

```
Wu <- function(u, repeats = 100) {
result <- numeric(repeats) 
for (i in seq_along(result)){
result[i] <- -((-u)^i)/(i * factorial(i))
}
return(sum(result) - log(u)-0.5772)
}
```

I've compared the results with values from a data table available here: https://pubs.usgs.gov/wsp/wsp1536-E/pdf/wsp_1536-E_b.pdf - see below (excuse verbose code - should have made a csv, with hindsight):

```
Wu_QC <- data.frame(u = c(1.0*10^-15, 4.1*10^-14,9.9*10^-13, 7.0*10^-12, 3.7*10^-11, 
2.3*10^-10, 6.8*10^-9, 5.7*10^-8, 8.4*10^-7, 6.3*10^-6,
3.1*10^-5, 7.4*10^-4, 5.1*10^-3, 2.9*10^-2,8.7*10^-1,
4.6,9.90),
Wu_table = c(33.9616, 30.2480, 27.0639, 25.1079, 23.4429, 
21.6157, 18.2291, 16.1030, 13.4126, 11.3978,
9.8043,6.6324, 4.7064,2.9920,0.2742,
0.001841,0.000004637))

Wu_QC$rep_100 <-  Wu(Wu_QC$u,100)
```

The good news is the formula gives identical results for repeats = 50, 100, 150 and 170 (so I've just given you the 100 version above). The bad news is that, while the function performs well for u < ~10^-3, it goes off the rails and gives negative outputs for numbers within an order of magnitude or so of 1. This doesn't happen when I just call the function on an individual number. i.e:

```
> Wu(4.6)
[1] 0.001856671
```

Which is the correct answer to 2sf.

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong and/or suggest a better way to code this equation? I think the problem is something to do with my for loop and/or an issue with the factorials generating infinite numbers as u gets larger, but I'm not at all certain.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the next two terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says on page 93 of your reference, W is also known as the exponential integral. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Convergent_series).

Then, e.g., the [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expint/vignettes/expint.pdf) `expint` provides a function to compute W(u):

```
library(expint)
expint(10^(-8))
# [1] 17.84347
expint(4.6)
# [1] 0.001841006
```

where the results are exactly as in your referred table.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks! Shame I've already spent a couple of days making a not as good version of that function, but c'est la vie.

Comment: @TimM, in that case you may consider accepting this answer.

Comment: Ah right. Done. Sorry, this was the first question I posted so I didn't really know the process. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that takes in a value together with the repetition times and outputs the required value:

```
w=function(u,l){
  a=2:l
  -0.5772-log(u)+u+sum(u^(a)*rep(c(-1,1),length=l-1)/(a)/factorial(a))
}
transform(Wu_QC,new=Vectorize(w)(u,170))
         u    Wu_table          new
1  1.0e-15 3.39616e+01 3.396158e+01
2  4.1e-14 3.02480e+01 3.024800e+01
3  9.9e-13 2.70639e+01 2.706387e+01
4  7.0e-12 2.51079e+01 2.510791e+01
5  3.7e-11 2.34429e+01 2.344290e+01
6  2.3e-10 2.16157e+01 2.161574e+01
7  6.8e-09 1.82291e+01 1.822914e+01
8  5.7e-08 1.61030e+01 1.610301e+01
9  8.4e-07 1.34126e+01 1.341266e+01
10 6.3e-06 1.13978e+01 1.139777e+01
11 3.1e-05 9.80430e+00 9.804354e+00
12 7.4e-04 6.63240e+00 6.632400e+00
13 5.1e-03 4.70640e+00 4.706408e+00
14 2.9e-02 2.99200e+00 2.992051e+00
15 8.7e-01 2.74200e-01 2.741930e-01
16 4.6e+00 1.84100e-03 1.856671e-03
17 9.9e+00 4.63700e-06 2.030179e-05
```

As the numbers become large the estimation is not quite good, so we should have to go further than 170! but R cannot do that. Maybe you can try other platforms. ie Python

Comment: Thanks for that! Looks like what you've done there is more than accurate enough for what I'm doing (and it cuts out the for loop). I'm expecting u to remain less than 1 for my application and accuracy to 2-3 sig. fig is more than enough. I'll give your code a try myself tomorrow.

In answer to your earlier question, the next two terms in the sequence would be:
+ u^5/(5*5!) - u^6/(6*6!) ...

Comment: I've tried your function with slight tweaks. It works well with the sample data and individual data points, but not with my real data. Here's a simplified version:

    well_func <- function(u,l = 100){
    a=2:l
    -0.5772-log(u)+u+sum(u^(a)*rep(c(-1,1),length=l-1)/(a)/factorial(a))
    }
    data <- data.frame(u = c(0.864, 0.288, 0.144))
    data$Wu <- Vectorize(well_func (data$u, 100))

This gives Wu = 0.251, 0.773, 1.32 (rounded), not ~0.27, 0.93, 1.5, as per the table (link above). However:

    well_func(0.251)

(etc) give the right answer. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The table might be running this in python or other languages that takes bigger factorials. The bigger the number, the less acurrate the results are

Comment: The table is from 1962, so I doubt it was run in python! 

By the way, I have considered the possibility that the Table is wrong and my numbers are right, but I can't think of a good way to test that out so I'm just assuming the table is 100% accurate for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have solved this myself (though borrowing heavily from Onyambo's answer!) Here's my code:

```
well_func2 <- function (u, l = 100) {
    result <- numeric(length(u))
a <- 2:l
for(i in seq_along(u)){
result[i] <- -0.5772-log(u[i])+u[i]+sum(u[i]^(a)*rep(c(-1,1),length=l-1)/(a)/factorial(a))
}
return(result)
}
```

As far as I can tell so far, this matches the tabulated results well for u <5 (as did Onyambo's code), and it also gives the same result for vector vs single-value inputs.

Still needs a bit more testing, and there's probably a tidier way to code it using map() or similar instead of the for loop, but I'm happy enough for now. Thought I'd share in case anyone else has the same problem.